# the link with href # anchor does not open the #div

Tags: jquery, html, css, anchor, href

I put a select option list in the site that opens div according to option value. This works fine when you are in the site. However if I call the link directly in address bar like `x.ro/y.html#3` it shows me the div `#1` instead of div `#3`.

Here is the code (div id 1 is `display: none`, div id 2 is `display: block`):

```
$(function() {
  $('#articole').change(function(){
    $('.tiparticol').hide();
    $($(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<select id="articole"  onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
  <option value="#1">1</option>
  <option value="#2" select="selected">2</option>
</select>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post your full code on jsin or jsfiddle ? So, we can in details and help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get this behaviour by default. You need to check the `window.location.hash` on load and set the appropriate value.

Also note that you should remove the `onChange="window.location.href=this.value"` attribute from your HTML. You can set that in your unobtrusive jQuery `change` handler. Try this:

```
$(function() {
  // on change
  $('#articole').change(function() {
    window.location.hash = this.value;
    setOption(this.value);
  });

  // on load
  var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
  if (hash)
    setOption(hash);
});

function setOption(value) {
  $('.tiparticol').hide();
  $(value).show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help... i didn't understand the part with "You need to check the window.location.hash on load and set the appropriate value." With this the displayed block div disappeared but the called div is not shown.

Comment: At the end it works perfectly fine! i've just eliminated subst(1) from on load code

Comment: $(function() {
  // on change
  $('#articole').change(function() {
    window.location.hash = this.value;
    setOption(this.value);
  });

  // on load
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  if (hash)
    setOption(hash);
});

function setOption(value) {
  $('.tiparticol').hide();
  $(value).show();
}

Answer (score 0):

The option attribute should be `selected`, not `select`.

Check out [this working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmhkq2nx/)

Comment: Thank you! i didn't noticed